# C++ Program for Renaming Multiple Files at Once

Tags: c++

I have a directory full of JPG files named Slide1, Slide2, Slide3, etc and I want to rename them to a list of names I wrote in a txt file titled "names.txt". Each new name is on one line, so basically I need to read this txt file line-by-line and make each line the new name of a JPG file. I will need to do this for multiple directories, but I expect each one to only contain a max of 60 JPGs (I will use the same names.txt file to rename the JPGs in each directory because it does not matter if there are duplicate JPG names between the directories, it only matters that the no two JPGs in the same directory have the same name).

This is the code I have so far. I know one problem is that char oldname[] and char newname[] can't use the + operator. So how do I get char oldname[] for each JPG to be Slide1, Slide2, etc? As for char newname[], I thought maybe I need to read each line of names.txt as a string and then convert that string to char and set it as char newname[] but I don't know how to do that.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myNum;
    cout << "How many slides are there? Max 60." << endl;   
    cin >> myNum;

    if (myNum > 60)
           cout << "Add more names to names.txt in lyrics folder, then rerun program." << endl; 

    if (myNum <= 60)
    {       
        int nextNum = 1;
        fstream readname;
        readname.open("names.txt",ios::in);
        if (readname.is_open())
        {
            string line;
            while (getline(readname,line))
            {
                char oldname[] = "Slide" + nextNum + ".JPG";
                char newname[] = line + ".JPG"; 
                nextNum = nextNum++;
                if (nextNum == myNum+1)
                    break;
            }
            readname.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can explain how to do this using string instead of char, that would be fine too. This isn't an assignment, it's just a personal project, so there are no limits to what methods I can use.

Comment: If you're interested in a file system library (works quite closely to how .NET File System library does) for C++, you could take a look here: https://ecs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/CSE687/code/FileSystem-Windows/FileSystem.zip 
There is a version for Linux as well. This could help you manage the directories and such.

Comment: @Everyone - we generally avoid suggesting third-party libraries where the C++ STL provides the capability. The one exception is Hinnant's date/time library that is currently being incorporated by the C++ standard.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i am well aware of that. However, the OP said it was a personal project where "there are no limits to what methods he can use." This, in fact, is the first time I suggest a third-party library on this site. I just thought it could help him given how he probably needs OS API to properly handle directories in batches.

Comment: No worries. I was just making the general point. You may be 100% correct for this limited application.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that's why I did not put it in an answer or so.

Answer (score 3):

From C++11 we have a function `std::to_string` this takes a numeric value and returns a `std::string` object. More info at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Using that you can convert your code(in while loop) as follows:

```
std::string oldName = std::string("Slide") + std::to_string(nextNum) + ".JPG";
std::string newName = line + ".JPG";
```

Hope this helps,

Thanks

Comment: Note how Rajkumar isn't even trying to use a `char` array. This is important. When you do string manipulation, do it with a `string`. Using a `char` array ramps up the complexity by an order of magnitude or two.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `char[]` arrays at all. Just use `std::string` instead:

```cpp
std::string oldname = "Slide" + std::to_string(nextNum) + ".JPG";
// Or, if you are not using C++11 or later:
/*
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Slide" << nextNum << ".JPG";
std::string oldname = oss.str();
*/

string newname = line + ".JPG";
```